# Put into file : index of line and total numbers of specific pattern

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to invent a command which add to the file index of line where numbers of commas are less than 5 + numbers of comma in line. Let's assume result:

Let's assume input:

```
'abc','abc','abc','abc,'abc,'abc
'abc','abc','abc','abc,'abc,'abc,'abc
'abc','abc','abc','abc,'abc,'abc,'abc,'abc'
```

So in first line there are 5 commas, in second - 6 and in third - 7 
and the expected result:

```
Index: 2 Number of commas : 6
Index: 3 Number of commas : 7
```

I invented that command which put into errors.csv all contents of line if comma > 50.

```
awk -F , 'NF > 50' <filename.csv >> errors.csv
```

The hardest for me is - how to retrieve and put into file index of line ??
Could you support me?

Comment: it is not clear what you mean. Could you [edit] to give more details?

Comment: hello   , edited  my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this expected output using `NR` and `NF` variables of `awk`:

```
awk -F"," '{ if(NF > 6) printf("Index: %d Number of commas : %d\n", NR, NF-1); }' filename.csv
```

`NR` gives you the number of records in a file.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for, why there is %d and %d\n, could you explain me that ? Thanks

Comment: That is `format specifiers` of `printf`. REF: https://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output

Comment: Fazlin, I have one more question. Now I have to search all the files started from Act* if not contain more that 13 commas. But now except Comma numbers and Index I would like also put there file name. eg.Index : 15 , Number of commas: 13 , Filename : Act123.csv and so on

Comment: Use `FILENAME` which is built-in variable of `awk` to print filename. For searching all files starting with Act*, you can use a `for` loop around this `awk` command.